# Split string into n pieces (or pieces of length n)

Tags: code-golf, string

## The Challenge

In this challenge you have to do two different (but related) tasks depending of the order of the input.
Your program will recieve a string `s` and an integer `n` as input and will

- split `s` into pieces of length `n` if `s` comes first. The last element will be shorter if necessary.
- split `s` into `n` pieces of equal length if `n` comes first. If `len(s)` is not a multiple of `n` the first `len(s) mod n` elements will be one longer.

You may only take those 2 inputs. `s` will never contain only digits.

#### Notes

- You may use the reverse mapping. Note this in your answer if you do that.
- `s` will only contain [printable ASCII characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) (no newlines).
- You may not use any builtins that solve either those two tasks directly. All other builtins are allowed.
- You have to take both arguments from the same source.
- You may take the arguments in an ordered list or any other format which clearly indicates their order as long as it is unambiguous.
- You may take the input as one string/ stream and use a character which is not a valid input (like a nullbyte) to separate them.
- `n` will always be equal or less than the length of `s` and greater than zero.
- You may output the resulting list in any resonable format as long as it clearly indicates the particular pieces and their order.

## Example

**Input:**  `programming, 3`
The last element contains only 2 characters, because 11 is not divisible by 3.
**Output:** `["pro", "gra", "mmi", "ng"]`

**Input:** `3, programming`
11 is not a multiple of 3, so the first 2 elements will be one longer:
**Output:** `["prog", "ramm", "ing"]`

## Rules

- Function or full program allowed.
- [Default rules](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) for input/output.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so lowest byte-count wins. Tiebreaker is earlier submission.

## Test cases

The test cases got generated with this [Pyth program](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jk%5BJw%22%2C%20%22Kw%22%20-%3E%20%22.xcsJKcJsK&input=12%0Aprogramming&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=3%0Ahelloworld%0Ahelloworld%0A3%0A1%0Aprogramming%0Aprogramming%0A1%0A8%0Aprogramming%0Aprogramming%0A8%0A9%0Acode%20golf%0Acode%20golf%0A9&debug=0&input_size=2) (uses builtins, so no valid answer). Thanks to @FryAmTheEggman for providing the base version of that!

```
3, helloworld -> ['hell', 'owo', 'rld']
helloworld, 3 -> ['hel', 'low', 'orl', 'd']
1, programming -> ['programming']
programming, 1 -> ['p', 'r', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'a', 'm', 'm', 'i', 'n', 'g']
8, programming -> ['pr', 'og', 'ra', 'm', 'm', 'i', 'n', 'g']
programming, 8 -> ['programm', 'ing']
9, code golf -> ['c', 'o', 'd', 'e', ' ', 'g', 'o', 'l', 'f']
code golf, 9 -> ['code golf']
4, 133tspeak -> ['133', 'ts', 'pe', 'ak']
133tspeak, 4 -> ['133t', 'spea', 'k']
```

**Happy Coding!**

Comment: *You may not use any builtins that solve those two tasks.* Does that include other built-ins, such *get every n-th character from a string* or *split at occurrences*?

Comment: @Dennis This was just meant to rule out builtins that solve this directly. I clarified.

Comment: If our language does not support arrays, how should we output? Would a newline between each result of the string be acceptable?

Comment: Also, for languages where the input is an array of ambiguous numbers, what should the procedure be?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Can't happen. _s will never contain only digits_. Also _You may output the resulting list in any resonable format as long as it clearly indicates the particular pieces and their order_ which includes multiline output of course.

Comment: @DenkerAffe Let me clarify. The input to the program `65, "Hello!"` would be read by the program as `65,72,101,108,108,111,33`, so it cannot disambiguate which is the string and which isn't. To compensate, could one take a number that represents the order of the arguments? So the input could be `1 <n> <s>` or `0 <s> <n>`. Secondly, you say the input can have _printable ASCII characters_, including newlines, which would make my output ambiguous as well.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I don't count newlines as [printable ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters), so thats one problem solved. However, taking a number which indicates the input order would be a huge advantage, so I can't really allow that, sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38117/discussion-between-c-ob-and-denkeraffe).

Comment: I assume the answer is no, but can builtins that solve one task be used to solve the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## MATL, <s>46</s> <s>26</s> <s>21</s> <s>27</s> <s>29</s> 42 bytes

```
jtU?jtbUe!tn2Gn>?0t(]tgbw(}ie]!2t$X{Oc''Zt
```

[**Try it Online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=anRVP2p0YlVlIXRuMkduPj8wSihddGdidyh9aWVdITJ0JFh7T2MnJ1p0&input=OApwcm9ncmFtbWluZw) (Updated slightly to work with the latest version of the language)

**Explanation**

```
j           % Explicitly grab the first input as a string
t           % Duplicate
U           % Attempt to convert it to a number
?           % If the conversion to a number was successful
    j       % Explicitly grab the second input as a string
    t       % Duplicate the value
    b       % Bubble-up the first element in the stack
    U       % Convert to a number from a string
    e       % Reshape the string into a nGroup x nPerGroup matrix
    !       % Take the transpose
    t       % Duplicate the result
    n       % Number of characters in the repmat result
    2Gn     % Number of characters in the string
    >?      % If chars in repmat > chars in string
        O   % Zero
        t   % Duplicate 
        (   % Assign the last element to a null character (bug in MATL)
    ]       % End if statement
    t       % Duplicate this matrix
    g       % Convert to a logical matrix
    b       % Bubble-up the original string
    w       % Flip the top two elements
    (       % Assign the non-empty characters to the chars from the input string
}           % Else the string comes first
    i       % Explicitly grab the second input (the number)
    e       % Reshape the characters into an nPerGroup x nGroup 2D array
]           % End of if statement
!           % Take the transpose so it reads left-to-right
2           % Number literal
t           % Duplicate
$X{         % Call num2cell to convert to a cell array
Oc          % Null character
''          % Empty string
Zt          % Replace null chars with empty strings
            % Implicit display of stack contents
```

Comment: What are those unprintables that appear at the end of some list elements? Those are not part of the input and should therefore not be part of the output either.

Comment: Isn't `e` a prohibited builtin ?

Comment: Maybe replace `XUZN?...` by `U?...` and swap the two `if` branches. Also, you don't need the `3$`

Comment: @DenkerAffe Sorry about that. Should be fixed now.

Comment: @FliiFe Based on the comments on the initial post, `e` doesn't directly solve the problem, so I don't consider it to be prohibited, no.

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks! I had that at one iteration or another but it must have gotten lost.

Comment: @Suever Are you sure? I still see them in the online interpreter.

Comment: @DenkerAffe Thanks to you we found a bug in MATL! Also, apparently null characters are displayed differently across browsers. It is *now* fixed!

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 132 bytes

```
(s,t)=>+t?[...Array(-~(~-s.length/+t))].map((_,i)=>s.substr(i*t,t)):[...Array(s=+s)].map(_=>t.slice(p,p-=~((t.length-p-1)/s--)),p=0)
```

This is probably hopelessly over-engineered.

Comment: Well, my (now deceased) solution was grossly under-engineered. +1 for you

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (Firefox), <s>88</s> 87 bytes

```js
a=>b=>(s=+b?a:b,i=x=0,l=s.length,[for(c of s)if(r=s.slice(x,x+=+b||l/a+(i++<l%a)|0))r])
```

Call it like `(...)("programming")(3)` using Firefox 30+.

Answer (score 2):

### AWK, <strike>121</strike> <strike>130</strike> <strike>128</strike> 122 Bytes

```
$1~/^[0-9]+$/{s=1}{a=$(s+1)
b=s?$1:$2
$0=""
for(j=-b;j<=c=length(a);)$0=$0 substr(a,j+=b+s,b+(s=s&&j<c%b*(b+1)?1:0))" "}1
```

The only issue is if the first entry is a string that starts with a numeric value.  This would cause `AWK` to see the string as that number and the second entry as the string.

OK... fixed the numeric issue, but it added 9 bytes :(.

Reworked a bit to save a couple bytes.

Almost back to the original length. :)

Comment: OK, @DenkerAffe , fixed it to work in general and only (eventually) added 1 byte.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 119 bytes

```
->x,y{r=[t=0];x.to_s==x ?(r.push x[t...t+=y]while x[t]):x.times{r.push y[t...t+=y.size/x+(r[y.size%x]? 0:1)]};r[1..-1]}
```

And I take first place by 2 bytes...

Comment: Regex objects in Ruby can have values injected into them the same way strings can, so `x.scan(/.{,#{y}})` works just as well for splitting the strings in the first case. Or does that count as a builtin?

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 131 bytes

```
import Data.Lists
q(d,m)=splitPlaces$(d+1<$[1..m])++[d,d..]
a#b|all(`elem`['0'..'9'])a=q(divMod(length b)$read a)b|1<2=q(read b,0)a
```

Usage example:

```
*Main> "8" # "programming"
["pr","og","ra","m","m","i","n","g"]
*Main> "programming" # "8"
["programm","ing"]
```

How it works: the main work is done by the helper function `q` which takes a pair of numbers `(d,m)` and a string `s`. It first builds a list of `m` times `d+1` followed by infinite many `d` (e.g `(1,3)` -> `[2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,...]`). It then uses `splitPlaces` to split `s` into chunks of lengths given by the list. `splitPlaces` stops if `s` runs out of elements, so an infinite list is fine.

The main function `#` checks which parameter is the number `n` / string `str` and calls `q` with either `(div (length str) n, mod (length str) n)` or `(n, 0)` plus `str`.

Answer (score 0):

### Pyth, 181 bytes

Let's pretend the longest code in bytes wins \o/

```
DyGK@G0J:@G1"."1=YJV%lJKW<l@YN.EclJK=YXYN+@YN@YhN=Y.DYhN)FNr%lJK/-lJ%lJK/-lJ%lJKKW<l@YNsclJK=YXYN+@YN@YhN=Y.DYhN))RY)DPG=K@G1=J:@G0"."1=YJV/lJKW<l@YNK=YXYN+@YN@YhN=Y.DYhN))RY).xyQPQ
```

[Try it here !](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=DyGK%40G0J%3A%40G1%22.%221%3DYJV%25lJKW%3Cl%40YN.EclJK%3DYXYN%2B%40YN%40YhN%3DY.DYhN%29FNr%25lJK%2F-lJ%25lJK%2F-lJ%25lJKKW%3Cl%40YNsclJK%3DYXYN%2B%40YN%40YhN%3DY.DYhN%29%29RY%29DPG%3DK%40G1%3DJ%3A%40G0%22.%221%3DYJV%2FlJKW%3Cl%40YNK%3DYXYN%2B%40YN%40YhN%3DY.DYhN%29%29RY%29.xyQPQ%0A&input=%5B3%2C%20%20%22helloworld%22%5D&test_suite_input=%5B3%2C%20%20%22helloworld%22%5D&debug=0) (The online interpreter seem to have a bug, it displays the input while it should not)

Here's the output from the terminal:

```
» pyth split.pyth <<<'["helloworld", 3]' 
['hel', 'low', 'orl', 'd']
» pyth split.pyth <<<'[3, "Helloworld"]'
['Hell', 'owo', 'rld']
```

Seriously, I am open to new approach. I'm new to python, so I probably missed a few shorthands.

I mean, I think my answer is deseperate from the point it is longer than the javascript answer...

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and output?

Comment: Note the official solution under the header `testcases`. The testcases are generated by Pyth. The solution is `.xcsJKcJsK`, where `J` and `K` are the two arguments.

Comment: @KennyLau I added a link to the online pyth interpreter. Strangely, it outputs the input too while I'm sure it did not yesterday... Will try to fix that.

Comment: use spaces to suppress printing

Comment: @KennyLau spaces where ?

Comment: "J" would print while " J" would not. Spaces before the expression.

Comment: @KennyLau The problem is to figure out the expression that prints. It works on my computer without additional printing

Comment: Do you have debug mode? You can see which expression prints in debug mode.

Comment: @KennyLau Now it works (without modification). I really think it was a bug with the online interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

## C# (LINQPAD) - 335 bytes

```
var y=Util.ReadLine().Split(',');int x,j=0;var t=int.TryParse(y[0].Trim(),out x);x=x==0?int.Parse(y[1].Trim()):x;var i=t?y[1].Trim():y[0];var z="";if(!t){while(i.Substring(j).Length>x){z+=i.Substring(j).Length>x?i.Substring(j,x)+", ":"";j+=x;}z+=i.Substring(j);}else z=string.Join(", ",i.Split(x).Select(s=>string.Concat(s)));z.Dump();
```

The input reading part took up a bit of space. Winner of longest answer.

Usage #1:

```
$ 3, helloworld

>> hell, owo, rld
```

Usage #2:

```
$ helloworld, 3

>>hel, low, orl, d
```

Comment: owo what's this?

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 114 bytes

```php
[$t,$n,$p]=$argv;for(@+$p?$s=$n:$f=$n*($p=strlen($s=$p)/$n)%$n;$t;)echo$t=substr($s,$a+=$e,$e=$p+($i++<$f)|0),"
";
```

- String should not start with digits.
  (Replace `+@$p` with `is_numeric($p)` to fix.)
- Output should not contain a chunk "0".
  (Insert `~` for printable ASCII, `a&` for any ASCII before `$t;` to fix.)
- Run with `-nr` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/69f2fd868a9a43c7bfe7d72f517c2694fab9300a).

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>122</s> 118 bytes

```powershell
param($a,$b)if($a-is[int]){$a,$b=$b,((($l=$b|% Le*)-($c=$l%$a))/$a)}$a-split("(..{$b})"*$c+"(.{0,$b})"*$a.Length)-ne''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVLRaoMwFH33Ky4hnUkXuxX70A4K/YD@wRgjtdHKUnWa0YH1291N7KIbDJaHm9xz7jk3N6QqL6puTkrrnqawhbavZC3PjEpBDzxP8RDlzXNemBfeOnBLD4IxRjUerjPYqzmPGE22VM@o5PwBQ4eiptK5YYQtFi09dJzMaXKPWfsobqlc7FWRmROPChWGfRcEOxYALhYLCO2NyktZ62MIIGDHHBIig6jdLMO5GBTTcgHxqLCVSDhd7bKJaolpVZcZznvOiywcVFNkbDBFBSxvpe4iztyGzKfShrMPuQ3FUOIt1390d3aD1X9sft1s/XMIJ5sOskEgKY8KslKn@LRDeeJnsO8XKhvAj@QI93jppO/oImDjjTzoC1eoW8axaSol33xHRKyhaWysXENkR/dRIWA1ERlbaQm7W0HA4QozaJ3OfVBB1WelEqOO@J/p60DUqvnQBoE7/OZUAj04nFBGbhyJ1DvxUsKfvkUk6Pov)

Less golfed:

```powershell
param($a,$b)
if($a-is[int]){
    $length=$b|% Length
    $c=$length%$a
    $a,$b=$b,(($length-$c)/$a)  # recalc length and swap
}
$pattern="(..{$b})"*$c+"(.{0,$b})"*$a.Length
$parts=$a -split $pattern       # pattern like '(..{3})(..{3})(.{0,3})(.{0,3})(.{0,3})'
$parts -ne ''                   # output not empty parts
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 69 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{a.scan /.{1,#{b}}/ rescue b.scan /.{1,#{b.size.fdiv(a).ceil}}/}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3XXXtEnWSqhP1ipMT8xT09aoNdZSrk2pr9RWKUouTS1MVklBl9Iozq1L10lIyyzQSNfWSUzNzgGproYZpFyi4RSsVFOWnFyXm5mbmpSvpKBjHcoFEjXUUUCRiIVoWLIDQAA)