# Divide a string

Tags: code-golf, string

## Challenge

Given a string and a number, divide the string into *that many* equal-sized parts. For example, if the number is 3, you should divide the string into 3 pieces no matter how long the string is.

If the length of the string does not divide evenly into the number provided, you should round down the size of each piece and return a "remainder" string. For example, if the length of the input string is 13, and the number is 4, you should return four strings each of size 3, plus a remainder string of size 1.

If there is no remainder, you may simply not return one, or return the empty string.

The provided number is guaranteed to be less than or equal to the length of the string. For example, the input `"PPCG", 7` will not occur because `"PPCG"` cannot be divided into 7 strings. (I suppose the proper result would be `(["", "", "", "", "", "", ""], "PPCG")`. It's easier to simply disallow this as input.)

As usual, I/O is flexible. You may return a pair of the strings and the remainder string, or one list of strings with the remainder at the end.

## Test cases

```
"Hello, world!", 4 -> (["Hel", "lo,", " wo", "rld"], "!") ("!" is the remainder)
"Hello, world!", 5 -> (["He", "ll", "o,", " w", "or"], "ld!")
"ABCDEFGH", 2 -> (["ABCD", "EFGH"], "") (no remainder; optional "")
"123456789", 5 -> (["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"], "6789")
"ALABAMA", 3 -> (["AL", "AB", "AM"], "A")
"1234567", 4 -> (["1", "2", "3", "4"], "567")
```

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in each language wins.

Bonus points (not really ) for making your solution actually use your language's division operator.

Comment: Bonus points? Oh man I gotta do this

Comment: For the bonus, [Jelly, 3 bytes `;⁹/`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/6UeNO/f@Hl0f@/@8BFMnXUQjPL8pJUfxvDAA)

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77310/split-string-into-n-pieces-or-pieces-of-length-n?rq=1), but neither part is quite the same as this challenge.

Comment: To make it clearer please add a testcase `PPCG` ,`7` so the remainder is `PPCG`

Comment: @JörgHülsermann That input is disallowed. I have added more details pertaining to that type of input and reformatted things to be more clear.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>63</s> 59 bytes

```python
s,n=input()
b=len(s)/n
exec'print s[:b];s=s[b:];'*n
print s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v1gnzzYzr6C0REOTK8k2JzVPo1hTP48rtSI1Wb2gKDOvRKE42iop1rrYtjg6ySrWWl0rjwsq/v@/uqGRsYmpmbmFpbqOgikA)

Comment: Well done! I really don't think this can be golfed any further.

Answer (score 5):

## PHP>=7.1, 75 bytes

```php
[,$s,$d]=$argv;print_r(preg_split('/.{'.(strlen($s)/$d^0).'}\K/',$s,$d+1));
```

[Testcases](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/73efe68d002d61949b9d550f86ba52887009babc)

## PHP>=7.1, 52 bytes

print only the remainder

```php
[,$s,$d]=$argv;echo substr($s,(strlen($s)/$d^0)*$d);
```

[Test Cases](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1c139a47686ded9bc3dff5ae27c90ec3dfe5045e)

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 62 bytes

`#` is an operator taking a `String` and an `Int`, and returning a list of `String`s.

Use as `"Hello, world!"#4`.

```hs
s#n|d<-length s`div`n=[take(d+n*0^(n-i))$drop(i*d)s|i<-[0..n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7LCsIwEEX3fkV9LBJtg9b6RIX6FnTlUioNJthgnEqSWgT/vVYLIribc@6dYSKqL1zK7EoFjAUYrujJ1BKQArgmV3pDOopTksApUeqBqpggxSkbDvdGCTg7E1QM9gYMxph89jJdhScbOZLD2USWDpm4hzA@GHrhiDWg3jwicATGNabiGxJ1hvVTjJxDkxAIgixDlXX@VGxbaawkK1dsy8Olf9l5S386my@Wq3XO7ptbbtvrdHv9wbew9af@zs@x/ZMXN18)

## How it works

- `s` is the input string and `n` is the number of non-remainder pieces.
- `d` is the length of each "normal" piece. `div` is integer division.
- The list comprehension constructs `n+1` pieces, with the last being the remainder.

  - `i` iterates from `0` to `n`, inclusive.
  - For each piece, first the right amount (`i*d`) of initial characters are `drop`ped from the beginning of `s`, then an initial substring is `take`n from the result.
  - The substring length taken should be `d`, except for the remainder piece.

    - The actual remainder must be shorter than `n`, as otherwise the normal pieces would be lengthened instead.
    - `take` returns the whole string if the length given is too large, so we can use any number `>=n-1` for the remainder piece.
    - The expression `d+n*0^(n-i)` gives `d` if `i<n` and `d+n` if `i==n`. It uses that `0^x` is `1` when `x==0`, but `0` if `x>0`.

Comment: I'll need to watch for where I can use list comprehensions.

Answer (score 5):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 21 bytes

20 bytes of code, +1 for `-n` flag.

```
a~C(#a//b*XX)XbP$$$'
```

Takes inputs as command-line arguments; outputs strings and remainder newline-separated. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/sc5ZQzlRXz9JKyJCMyIpQEVFRf3///@6Bf8NjYxNTM3MLSz/mwIA)

#### Explanation

Fun with regex operations!

Let's take `abcdefg` as our string and `3` as our number. We construct the regex `(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})`, which matches three runs of two characters and stores them in three capture groups. Then, using Pip's regex match variables, we can print 1) the list of capture groups `["ab";"cd";"ef"]`, and 2) the remainder of the string that wasn't matched `"g"`.

```
                      a,b are cmdline args; XX is the regex `.` (match any one character)
    #a//b             Len(a) int-divided by b: the length of each chunk
         *XX          Apply regex repetition by that number to `.`, resulting in something
                        that looks like `.{n}`
  C(        )         Wrap that regex in a capturing group
             Xb       Repeat the whole thing b times
a~                    Match the regex against a
               P$$    Print $$, the list of all capture groups (newline separated via -n)
                  $'  Print $', the portion of the string after the match
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>68 67</s> 65 bytes

- @musicman123 saved 2 bytes:output without enclosing with `[]`
- Thanks to @Chas Brown for 1 Byte: `x[p*i:p+p*i]` as `x[p*i][:p]`

```python
def f(x,n):p=len(x)/n;print[x[p*i:][:p]for i in range(n)],x[p*n:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FclBCoAgEAXQq0ytNIQgWhntu4O4CNQS5DuIkJ3e6G0fv/XOWHp3PlAQTUFq3pOHaHLGxiWimmZ4itoazTbkQpEiqJy4vIC06l9o24MYD59SVvTkktwwqlX2Dw)

Comment: Save 1 byte by replacing `x[p*i:p+p*i]` with `x[p*i:][:p]`

Comment: +1 for `:p`  Well done outgolfing the other Python answers!

Comment: Haha.. that was not intended at all.... :p

Comment: This answer has now been [outgolfed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/129315/69054)

Answer (score 4):

## C++14, <s>209</s> 180 bytes

That's a bit too long, but uses the division operator:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using q=std::string;using z=std::vector<q>;z operator/(q s,int d){int p=s.length()/d,i=0;z a;for(;i<d+1;){a.push_back(s.substr(i++*p,i^d?p:-1));}return a;}
```

Usage:

```
vector<string> result = string("abc")/3;
```

Online version: http://ideone.com/hbBW9u

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 9 bytes

```
cz*L/lzQS
```

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=cz%2aL%2FlzQS&input=5%0AHello%2C+world%21)

#### How it works

First `Q` is autoinitialized to `eval(input())` and `z` is autoinitialized to `input()`.

```
cz*L/lzQSQ
     lz      length of z
    /  Q     integer division by Q
  *L         times every element of
        SQ       [1, 2, …, Q]
cz           chop z at those locations
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
Ld⁹x,1$}R⁸ṁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98n5VHjzgodQ5XaoEeNOx7ubPx/eLlS5KOmNVmPGuYc2qYLBYe2/f@v5AHUkq@jUJ5flJOiqKSjgCng6OTs4ubq7gFiGxoZm5iamVtYgiV8HJ0cfR2V/pvoKJjqKBiBSWMA)

Comment: Fails for the "123456789", 5 testcase

Comment: Completely misread the challenge. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 107 bytes

```rust
fn f(s:&str,n:usize)->(Vec<&str>,&str){let c=s.len()/n;((0..n).map(|i|&s[i*c..i*c+c]).collect(),&s[c*n..])}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZJdT8IwFIbv@RXdLkiLs8oYfjAlKX5xAbfeLItZapcsKR2uRROB3z7PaUKEKMZdvKc5532fnXRrVta1pSGLojKUkXWHwFNYqxr3ot4CWtJwqrSuI/JRN/o1CCOSsIjQdyWDDEfQCGGMBSxYwBbmUIOQsfQfvOE@z@M8dMf058YT0f87U0zu7h8en6Zgjr9x2MW4nyDgSLofD5LhxeXV9eE2fczGKAOUBGXoOd57ZJOZmIi5AO9gb5EZZsXE69wjxN@7HN7zj02QgK4dY9lUxmkTwPu1Jk5ZZ8kSwHBfaWeLH7ikdtS1ronMaGWrT8VOx/RZyRvsjSNUttbKEXlruVbwL5yZlNJzzg3ji2JJN9Wma7OqJzkHOZE547LWWklHGcQz2TOc52zbtl8)

Formatted:

```rust
fn q129259(s: &str, n: usize) -> (Vec<&str>, &str) {
    let c = s.len() / n;
    ((0..n).map(|i| &s[i * c..i * c + c]).collect(), &s[c * n..])
}
```

This simply `map`s indices onto the correct slices of the source `str` (`collect`ing into a `Vec`) and slices out the remainder.

Unfortunately, I cannot make this a closure (74 bytes):

```rust
|s,n|{let c=s.len()/n;((0..n).map(|i|&s[i*c..i*c+c]).collect(),&s[c*n..])}
```

as the compiler fails with

```rust
error: the type of this value must be known in this context
 --> src\q129259.rs:5:18
  |
5 |          let c = s.len() / n;
  |                  ^^^^^^^
```

and if I provide the type of `s:&str`, the lifetimes are wrong:

```rust
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements
 --> src\q129259.rs:6:27
  |
6 |          ((0..n).map(|i| &s[i * c..i * c + c]).collect(), &s[c * n..])
  |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the body at 4:18...
 --> src\q129259.rs:4:19
  |
4 |       (|s: &str, n| {
  |  ___________________^
5 | |          let c = s.len() / n;
6 | |          ((0..n).map(|i| &s[i * c..i * c + c]).collect(), &s[c * n..])
7 | |      })(s, n)
  | |______^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
 --> src\q129259.rs:6:27
  |
6 |          ((0..n).map(|i| &s[i * c..i * c + c]).collect(), &s[c * n..])
  |                           ^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the body at 3:58...
 --> src\q129259.rs:3:59
  |
3 |   fn q129259<'a>(s: &'a str, n: usize) -> (Vec<&str>, &str) {
  |  ___________________________________________________________^
4 | |     (|s: &str, n| {
5 | |          let c = s.len() / n;
6 | |          ((0..n).map(|i| &s[i * c..i * c + c]).collect(), &s[c * n..])
7 | |      })(s, n)
8 | | }
  | |_^
note: ...so that expression is assignable (expected (std::vec::Vec<&'a str>, &'a str), found (std::vec::Vec<&str>, &str))
 --> src\q129259.rs:4:5
  |
4 | /     (|s: &str, n| {
5 | |          let c = s.len() / n;
6 | |          ((0..n).map(|i| &s[i * c..i * c + c]).collect(), &s[c * n..])
7 | |      })(s, n)
  | |_____________^
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 92 bytes

```
(.+)¶(.+)
$2$*1¶$.1$*1¶$1
(1+)¶(\1)+
$1¶$#2$*1¶
\G1(?=1*¶(1+))
$1¶
¶¶1+

O^$`.

¶1+$

O^$`.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fQ09b89A2EMmlYqSiZXhom4qeIYQ25NIwBEvGGGpqc6mAhJQhSrhi3A017G0NtYCSQCWaYEmuQ9sObTPU5uLyj1NJ0OPiAnFUYLz//z1Sc3LydRTK84tyUhS5TAE) Explanation: The first stage converts the number of parts to unary and also takes the length of the string. The second stage then divides the length by the number of parts, leaving any remainder. The third stage multiplies the result by the number of parts again. This gives us the correct number of strings of the correct length, but they don't have the content yet. The number of parts can now be deleted by the fourth stage. The fifth stage reverses all of the characters. This has the effect of switching the original content with the placeholder strings, but although it's now in the right place, it's in reverse order. The placeholders have served their purpose and are deleted by the sixth stage. Finally the seventh stage reverses the characters back into their original order.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 36 bytes

```perl6
{$^a.comb.rotor($a.comb/$^b xx$b,*)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBtS8MwFIU/r7/iLgRJZm3t21SGSjdf9mH7BdZBa1MstM1IC26M/faaG50W9uXc5J6T50C2QlXTvt7DRQH30B/oJnU@ZJ05SnZSMfpzc@kmg92OZvaEH/tCKmBV2YiWw8Ea1W5CmDN55AlxkpYl@SV3Z9aoTfdQMHptA/W4dezJUlSVtOFLqiofExtCuHoA9oZ7fSPaw6F9HDpD3vUcEw5MK5QtdJ8ClKjTssmF4tYZMPoDGp6hnqDmrAwSw/p1PF88Pb@8LrXj/z7EFQbNGqNY3sj/0hnIbVfKJq3Qs4jnB2E0vbm9G7R7SPBRApQQJTI0E8TmVTyP17E2glPxClPx3OjahOMBf/BZZ3TMYoR/Aw)

Returns a list of lists of strings, where the last element is the remainder (if there is one).

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                                  }  # Anonymous code block
 $^a.comb                             # Split the string into a list of chars
         .rotor(                  )   # And split into
                            xx$b      # N lists
                $a.comb/$^b           # With string length/n size
                                ,*    # And whatever is left over
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python, <s>82</s> <s>76</s> 74 bytes

```python
def G(h,n):l=len(h);r=l/n;print[h[i:i+r]for i in range(0,n*r,r)],h[l-l%n:]
```

Well, looks like this qualifies for the bonus points.  <sub><sub>May I please receive a cookie instead?</sub></sub> <sup><sup>Oh wait, they aren't real? Darn...</sup></sup>

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCsIwEAXQq4wFIdERRVyldF3vELIQmjoDw08ZCsXTx/e23y4Nz96XutIchBGTTVYRJI4@2R3j5oo9S9akVy9rc1JSkH/wreHBuDh7LCzZbnZGKn0Ow7uaNaajuS2ngV@x/wE)

Comment: Would you prefer [a cookie](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies), or [saving 6 bytes by factoring out `len(h)`](https://tio.run/##DcpBCoMwEAXQq0yFQlKnVEpXEdf2DpJFwWgGhh8ZBPH0qW/9tnPPBe9a57TQ6DLDBx00wWXf26Av9JsJ9ilPEqS1uBQjIQHZD2tyHeNhbD6219Cn3hFirKNrvkm1MB3FdL41/PH1Dw "Python 2 – Try It Online")? :)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 77 bytes

```js
(s,d,n=s.length)=>[s.match(eval(`/.{${n/d|0}}/g`)).slice(0,d),s.slice(n-n%d)]
```

Returns an array of two elements: the divided string parts and the remainder part.

### Test Snippet

```js
f=
(s,d,n=s.length)=>[s.match(eval(`/.{${n/d|0}}/g`)).slice(0,d),s.slice(n-n%d)]
```

```html
<div oninput="O.innerHTML=I.value&&J.value?JSON.stringify(f(I.value,+J.value)):''">String: <input id=I> Number: <input id=J size=3></div>
<pre id=O>
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 18 bytes

```
¯W=Ul fV)òW/V pUsW
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=r1c9VWwgZlYp8lcvViBwVXNX&input=IjEyMzQ1Njc4OSIKNSAtUQ==) (uses `-Q` flag to visualize the output)

#### Explanation

```
¯W=Ul fV)òW/V pUsW  : Implicit: U = input string, V = input integer
   Ul fV            : Floor U.length to a multiple of V.
 W=                 : Assign this value to variable W.
¯       )           : Take the first W characters of U (everything but the remainder).
         òW/V       : Partition this into runs of length W / V, giving V runs.
              pUsW  : Push the part of U past index W (the remainder) to the resulting array.
                    : Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python, <s>95, 87, 76</s> 73 Bytes

```python
def f(s,n):
 a=[];i=len(s)/n
 while n:a+=s[:i],;s=s[i:];n-=1
 print a+[s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcbBCoQgEADQu18xdVJyWXahi@K9fxAPQkoDwxhNEH299U5vv8@t8b/3tVSoWiwbpyCHmDwGKqzFfFnBtSEVYJenINFhsl7eoEueP@GnYD@QT8hTlNSrHpdC1Cxc7aB1GC3Mpj8)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I added a "Try it online" link to your post. I think you can slightly shorten your solution by making it a full program rather than a function. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcaxCsMgEADQ3a8wmZQYSgJZlNv7D@IgVMjBcUrOEvr1Nm967dfPyvsY4hiQ27cbqzLEFBCosBH7YnWfSEWzzwtI9JhckCfoU@AVNtUu5K7zEiWNYeZ3IapO3/WizzQ7fdg/ "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

```
²g¹‰`s¹.D)R£
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0Kb0QzsfNWxIKD60U89FM@jQ4v//Tbg8UnNy8nUUyvOLclIUAQ)

#### Explanation

```
²g¹‰`s¹.D)R£
²g           # Push length of string
  ¹          # Push amount of pieces
   ‰         # divmod of the two
    `s       # Flatten the resulting array and flip it around
      ¹.D    # Repeat the resulting length of the pieces amount of pieces times(wow that sounds weird)
         )   # Wrap stack to array
          R  # Reverse (so the remainder is at the end)
           £ # Split the input string into pieces defined by the array
```

Comment: [**9 bytes**](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fJd3zUcOGI@2eF3YcXnNo8f//Hqk5Ofk6CuX5RTkpilwmAA) by reversing the input-order.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 16 bytes

```
kʰ↙Xḍ₎Ylᵛ&ht↙X;Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3wP/vUhkdtMyMe7uh91NQXmfNw62y1jBKQiHXk///RCtFKHqk5OfnWCuX5RTkpiko6JrE6GGKmIDFHJ2cXVzd3DyUdIxDX0MjYxNTM3MISJu3j6OTo66ikY4wkCzUupDw1r6RSISe1pCS1qFghJz8vXQ8kpRALAA)

Takes input as a list `[string, number]` and outputs as a list `[remainder, parts]`. (Commas were replaced with semicolons in the "Hello, world!" test cases for clarity, since the string fragments don't get printed with quotes.)

```
                    The input
 ʰ                  with its first element
k ↙X                having the last X elements removed
    ḍ               and being cut into a number of pieces
     ₎              where that number is the last element of the input
      Y             is Y
       lᵛ           the elements of which all have the same length,
         &          and the input
          h         's first element
           t↙X      's last X elements
              ;     paired with
               Y    Y
                    are the output.
```

(I also replaced a comma in the code with a semicolon for a consistent output format. [With the comma](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3wP/vUhkdtMyMe7uh91NQXmfNw62y1jBKQiE7k///RCtFKHqk5OfnWCuX5RTkpiko6JrE6GGKmIDFHJ2cXVzd3DyUdIxDX0MjYxNTM3MISJu3j6OTo66ikY4wkCzUupDw1r6RSISe1pCS1qFghJz8vXQ8kpRALAA), cases with no remainder would just output the parts without an empty remainder, and as nice as that is for some purposes, I don't actually know why it works that way...)

After this came out to be a whole 16 bytes, I tried to make something based on `+₁ᵗ⟨ġl⟩` work, but as the fixes got longer and longer I decided that I would just stick with my original solution for now.

Answer (score 2):

### C(gcc), 72 bytes

```
d;f(s,n)char*s;{for(d=strlen(s)/n;n--;puts(""))s+=write(1,s,d);puts(s);}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##JYw7DsIwEAX7nMK42gVbKFCu3HMDCkQR@QORjB15jSiinN2Q8MqZ0bP6YW1rjgKwSmifQ9kzzSEXcIZriT4B4zFR0pqmd2WQEpEP5lPG6qFXrBz@BSMt7TWMCbCbO/Hb@iaq53q7CyPkxceYxTWX6Hb9SdLWBFgDJc5I3bKR9gU)

Answer (score 2):

## Excel Formula, <s>185</s> <s>173</s> <s>165</s> <s>161</s> 149 bytes

The following should be entered as an array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=MID(A1,(ROW(OFFSET(A1,,,B1+1))-1)*INT(LEN(A1)/B1)+1,INT(LEN(A1)/B1)*ROW(OFFSET(A1,,,B1+1))/IF(ROW(OFFSET(A1,,,B1+1))=B1+1,1,ROW(OFFSET(A1,,,B1+1))))
```

Where `A1` contains your input (e.g. `12345678`) and `B1` contains the divisor. This also uses Excel's division operator for a bonus.

After entering the formula as an array formula, highlight it in the formula bar and evaluate it using <kbd>F9</kbd> to return the result, for example:

[image: Excel formula evaluation showing split groups]

**-12 bytes:** replace each `INDIRECT("1:"&B1+1)` with `OFFSET(A1,,,B1+1)` to save 2 bytes per occurence, plus some tidying removing redundant brackets.

**-8 bytes:** remove redundant `INDEX` function.

**-4 bytes:** rework "remainder" handling.

**-12 bytes:** remove redundant `INT(LEN(A1)/B1)` by offsetting array generated by `ROW(OFFSET(A1,,,B1+1))` by -1.

Answer (score 2):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 62 bytes

```
YpC<c-r>=strlen('<c-r>"')
<esc>jYp<c-x>"aDkk:s:\n:/
C<c-r>=<c-r>"
<esc>"bDkkqq@blha
<esc>q@a@q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P7LA2SZZt8jOtrikKCc1T0MdzFNS1@SySS1OtsuKLAAKVNgpJbpkZ1sVW8XkWelzQXVAVELUKSUB5QsLHZJyMhIhIoUOiQ6F//97pObk5OsolOcX5aQocpn81y0DAA)

takes input as 2 lines, returns the divisions on separate lines.

`a` is useful here to append a newline after the current character.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>77</s> 76 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to musicman523.*

```python
def f(s,n):l=len(s);print[s[i:i+l/n]for i in range(0,l-n+1,l/n)]+[s[l-l%n:]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNo1gnT9MqxzYnNU@jWNO6oCgzryS6ODrTKlM7Rz8vNi2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw0AnRzdP21AHKKUZqw1Ul6Obo5pnFRv7P01D3SM1JydfR6E8vygnRVFdR8FEkwuLqClY1NHJ2cXVzd0DKGAEFjA0MjYxNTO3sEQo8XF0cvR1BPKNkVWADf4PAA)

Comment: This is one byte shorter as a function. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcrNCgIhEADgV7GFwMlZ@qGT0b13kDksrNbAMIq6RE9ve/6@8uufrLcx1phMsg0VvDwlqm3wKJW1hxbYs5OzUsrVsGE1ddF3tBeUWd0VdwJy@5NZjuqJRrIn1rJ1CzDC9IoiGc03V1kPE97pDw "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 53 bytes

```ruby
->s,n{a=s.scan(/.{,#{s.size/n}}/);[a[0,n],a[n,n]*'']}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZhvzX9euWCevOtG2WK84OTFPQ1@vWke5GsjJrErVz6ut1de0jk6MNtDJi9VJjM4DUlrq6rG1/wsU0qLTU0uK9ZIz8nMLdBTA7JL8@MzY/4ZGxiamZuYWllymAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, <s>120</s> 88 bytes (thanks to Ørjan Johansen!)

Does `div` count as the division operator?

I am curious how I could cut this down, I haven't learned all the tricks yet.

```
q=splitAt;x!s|n<-div(length s)x,let g""=[];g s|(f,r)<-q n s=f:g r,(a,b)<-q(n*x)s=(g a,b)
```

Comment: A quick rewrite with the most basic tricks: ``t=splitAt;x!s|n<-div(length s)x,let g""=[];g s|(f,r)<-t n s=f:g r,(a,b)<-t(n*x)s=(g a,b)``. So, (1) A repeatedly used identifier may be abbreviated, especially if it's long. (2) Guards and pattern guards are almost always shorter than `let` ... `in`, `where` and `if` `then` `else`. (3) Pattern matching is often better than equality testing. (OK, that `let` in a pattern guard isn't that basic, I recently learned it from someone else here.) And check out https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19255/tips-for-golfing-in-haskell .

Comment: Also, take a look at [Tips for golfing in Haskell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19255/tips-for-golfing-in-haskell) for some useful tricks.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Thanks! I forgot that semicolons were valid, and that `let` in the guard is pretty devious. But shorter code is more readable, right?

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 58 bytes

```
{#~Partition~a,#2}&@@TakeDrop[#,(a=Floor[Length@#/#2])#2]&
```

Pure function taking a list of characters and a positive integer as input. For example, the last test case is called by

```
{#~Partition~a,#2}&@@TakeDrop[#,(a=Floor[Length@#/#2])#2]&[{"1","2","3","4","5","6","7"},4]
```

and returns:

```
{{{"1"}, {"2"}, {"3"}, {"4"}}, {"5", "6", "7"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ohm, 3 bytes (non-competing?)

```
lvσ
```

Non competing because the built-in isn't implemented yet in TIO and i have no PC handy to test whether it works in the latest pull in the repo.

<s>Built-in ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. I used the wrong built-in... But hey there is still an other one laying around.</s> Now I used the wrong built-in two times (or one built-in works wrong with remainders).

Do I get bonus points because `v` is (floor) division?

Comment: This doesn't split in the way required. e.g. the `Hello, world!` `5` testcase is wrong. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/I/f//8Pz//z1Sc3LydRTK84tyUhS5TAE "Ohm – Try It Online")

Comment: Well I'm going to look for another built-in....

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 16 bytes

```
{_,2$//_2$<@@>s}
```

Anonymous block expecting the arguments on the stack and leaves the result on the stack after.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1fWPe/Ol7HSEVfP95IxcbBwa649n9dakqs9X9TBSWP1JycfB2F8PyinBRFJQA)

#### Explanation

Expects arguments as `number "string"`.

```
_,              e# Copy the string and get its length.
  2$            e# Copy the number.
    /           e# Integer divide the length by the number.
     /          e# Split the string into slices of that size.
      _         e# Copy the resulting array.
       2$       e# Copy the number.
         <      e# Slice the array, keeping only the first <number> elements.
          @@    e# Bring the number and original array to the top.
            >   e# Slice away the first <number> elements,
             s  e# and join the remaining elements into a string.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://www.jsoftware.com), 26 bytes

```
(]$~[,(<.@%~#));]{.~0-(|#)
```

Apart from elminating spaces and intermediate steps, this hasn't been golfed. I expect that I've taken the long way somehow, what with my parentheses and argument references (`[` and `]`).

See [Jupyter notebook](https://github.com/DaneWeber/JlangLearning/blob/master/Divide%20a%20string%20-%20Programming%20Puzzles%20%26%20Code%20Golf.ipynb) for test cases, such as the following:

```
   5 chunk test2
┌──┬───┐
│He│ld!│
│ll│   │
│o,│   │
│ w│   │
│or│   │
└──┴───┘
```

Comment: Thanks.  Read too fast.  Comment removed

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>79</s> 63 bytes

*-16 from Giuseppe fixing the indexing*

```r
function(s,n,k=nchar(s),l=k%/%n)substring(s,0:n*l+1,c(1:n*l,k))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxNCsIwEEb3nmJclCY6YAOuhCz87wG8QK1JWxImMkkRTx8j/VYfj8fjbHW2M/VpCiQiEjpN/dixiBK9dtWuIhnnZ0w80VCE5kAbv1XYC/V/6KTMVtSt8T4gfAL717pGgL1cFXw8nS/X270tZAEPE1MJQQc@0GAYljDYwPAOMRme0rfYqpG57Ac)

Built around giving vector inputs to `substring()`

Comment: [63 bytes](https://tio.run/##JYxNCsIwEEb3nmJclCY6YAOuhCz87wG8QK1JWxImMkkRTx8j/VYfj8fjbHW2M/VpCiQiEjpN/dixiBK9dtWuIhnnZ0w80VCE5kAbv1XYC/V/6KTMVtSt8T4gfAL717pGgL1cFXw8nS/X270tZAEPE1MJQQc@0GAYljDYwPAOMRme0rfYqpG57Ac) -- simplified the indexing a bit.

Comment: @Giuseppe Haha, I must have tried every variant of adding and multiplying on the index, but missed that one. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript, 49 bytes

```
d=(s,n)=>s.match(eval(`/.{1,${0|s.length/n}}/g`))
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##HcqxCsIwFEDRvV/xLA55EBMFB6HE2T9wEKEhiW3lmUgSstR@e6ze8XKeuuhk4vTOu3Kq1SqWuEd1TuKlsxmZK5pYL8V84Nt5/0mCnB/yKP2yyKFHrEVHiC6DAsvaiyMKHK4hkt20HI7YNY8Qgf0VTP5HsYE1E3wK5ASFga3zFu/Y1S8)

```js
d=(s,n)=>s.match(eval(`/.{1,${0|s.length/n}}/g`))

var ret = d("######.######..#####..########..##.##..##.##.....##.....######.######.##.....##..#####.....##.....##.....##...####.....##......####...######", 5);
for (var r in ret)
    console.log(ret[r]);
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
î╩╘30¥♂┴ÿ&╕¡
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8ccad433309d0bc19826b8ad&i=%22Hello,+world%21%22,+4%0A%22Hello,+world%21%22,+5%0A%22ABCDEFGH%22,+2%0A%22123456789%22,+5%0A%22ALABAMA%22,+3%0A%221234567%22,+4%0A&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-P`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
òUÊzV)sV
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVA&code=8lXKelYpc1Y&input=IkhlbGxvLCB3b3JsZCEiCjQ)

```
òUÊzV)sV     :Implicit input of string U & integer V
ò            :Partitions of U of length
 UÊ          :  Length of U
   zV        :  Floor divided by V
     )       :End partition
      sV     :Slice off the first V elements
             :Implicitly join and output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell v3+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <strike>72</strike>, 80 bytes

Assumes `$s` contains the input string; `$n` contains the number of characters per "piece".  This also assumes that "StrictMode" is off.  Otherwise, an error would be returned because of indexing further into an array than actually exists (i.e. if array has 4 elements and i call the non-existent 5th element).  With StrictMode off, PS doesn't care and it'll ignore the error.

```powershell
for($i = 0;$i -le $s.Length;$i+=$n+1){-join($s|% ToCharA*)[$i..($i+$n)]}
```

Using notation `($s|% ToCharA*)` i was able to save 1 character compared to `$s.ToCharArray()` : )

### Update:

Updated code to actually satisfy challenges requirements.
Again assumes `$s` contains the input string; however, this time `$n` contains the number of "pieces". The remainder is printed out last.  And i used PowerShell's division operator

```powershell
0..($n-1)|%{$p=[math]::Floor($s.length/$n)}{$s|% Su*($_*$p) $p}{$s|% Su*($n*$p)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvUqxgq6DuAWTm6yiU5xflpCiqW3Op5AFFTf4b6OlpqOTpGmrWqFarFNhG5yaWZMRaWbnl5OcXaagU6@Wk5qWXZOir5GnWVqsU16gqBJdqaajEa6kUaCqoFCCL5YHEav//BwA)

Comment: I believe you've misunderstood the question, the input is the *number* of pieces (excluding remainder).

Comment: Oh, you're right.  I mis-read the question last night : )
I'll post my updated solution when i have a chance.

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 152 bytes

Thanks @JörgHülsermann (brackets tip!)

```php
$c=$s=explode('|',readline());
while($s[1]--)$s[0]=preg_replace('/^'.($l[]=substr($s[0],0,strlen($c[0])/$c[1])).'/','',$s[0]);
$l[r]=$s[0];
print_r($l);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzNCoMwEITvPkULgWQh/h16sqHXvoOkYnWpwhKXxGIPvrtdvMzMBzPDEx/3B4uqwank8Me0jGj0rm3EfqQ5oAFosm2aCY1Kbe3zHMQr7zjip4vI1A@yKF@6MIpa79L3ndZozpKtrGTCYNQgCKVY7QEKXWqrtT1L8i/D6N1JTcZxDmsnDwTNcTyRaLGXbYk0XvfbHw)

Comment: Your PHP Way doesn't work cause it replaces not only at the beginning. `preg_replace` is an alternative or you can use `[,$s,$d]=$argv;print_r(array_slice(str_split($s,$l=strlen($s)/$d^0),0,$d)+[$d=>substr($s,$l*$d)]);`

Comment: Can you explain me with a example code why doesn't work my PHP code ?

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYvBCsMgEETvfseCCoYmh56sFHtOv0AktCIYWMKiKf18s3iamfcYKtQfTyokoLkg/epf/u2luUfbITloVvzLjllBC0ucJs05R9fOutVM@ElsMDD4fZmpYc1suGM@FCSe@saxRG2kNMNrK/hToxvLCqr7cW58Rm17vwA "PHP – Try It Online") It replaces all `A` in the first run

Comment: You can drop the array_walk construct if you use brackets [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBCsMgFET3nkP4fjAxoUsrwa7bE4gNrUgTkPDRlB7fiquZB2@GNqrXhTZivBgH9m5v9mFBXryuPBheNPtte4qCFzf7YcCWkzeU42fNkdIrRAHqCaPgyXlTvu9yZtElOcnWUzwEDw1RtZg94ggKJIDsEmrWhtmbTppR3o9zbQ8Jda1/ "PHP – Try It Online")

Comment: Nice tip ! I totally forgot

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/24359933eecf5ff28247f2d23729dcaee411261e a shorter solution needs PHP 7.1

Comment: Your way can be golfed to this [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYxBDsIgEEWvoskkMJEWF@4Q3XqHpjZVsDaZFDKDenxk8zfvvZ/fuZ6vuS2tUrQBMRDQw8zL170SayheClPcNAhaCA5C1zkE8ZnjMnHMND@jVvaueg00jF4@j1Y03RwNFMReWWWUatfoMq9bmRqkw8D@AjKiq7XeIlEyu19iCvt6@gM "PHP – Try It Online") or [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LclBCsIwEEbhq2j5Fw1O0YW7GN16h1JKNVELQxNmoh4/RnHzFt9Lj1QOp1TLs@aWoARvHCa5v@wtSovsNAuHpYWaLbyF7zoLdfq81DFKSDxdQ73UNLQjZGPA/fD/X/@hTTIveazAm17cEToYW0o5B@ZIq3cU9uuy/wA "PHP – Try It Online") use substr_replace and for using PHP 7.1 -4 Bytes for the short list syntax

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 94 bytes

```python
i=input().split('|')
s,n=i[0],int(i[1])
c=len(s)//n
while n:print(s[:c]);s=s[c:];n-=1
print(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lck7CoQwEADQPqewMwN@EZvIFNnaPUFIFQQHwmxwIrLg3SML@9qXvnn/8FQKIXE6s4ZOUqSs67sGJQ0jucE3xFmTGz2ogHFjLdD3rK6d4laxScfvxZngYREUF4xfuMVR/QdKsat92be95wc)

Comment: Assuming the input is in a variable is not a [valid input method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).

Comment: What mean this _As usual, I/O is flexible._ ? Anyway thanks, I edit my answer...

Comment: PPCG's standard methods *are* pretty flexible. Just not quite that much.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 57 bytes

```python
def f(s,n):k=len(s)/n;print zip(*[iter(s)]*k)[:n],s[k*n:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchBCoAgEADAr5inXRGCoIvRvT@It5REWUWFqM9vzXHqM65CC/PpgwjQNaFJe/YEHWfaaos0xBsrKBuHb/86ldAacrrbpMg4DiAPn3PR4i4tn5PUYkX@AA)

Comment: I... think I'll wait for OP's judgement on that output format.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pF`, 43 bytes

```perl
$p=@F/($q=<>);say substr$_,0,$p,''while$q--
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@lwNbBTV9DpdDWxk7TujixUqG4NKm4pEglXsdAR6VAR129PCMzJ1WlUFf3/3@P1JycfB2F8vyinBRFLtN/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwN/usWuAEA)

Comment: Apparently.  I misread the spec.

Answer (score 0):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 64 bytes

```forth
: f >r i /mod rot r> 0 do over 2dup cr type + loop rot cr type ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7LCsJADEX3fsU1W23VPnwVClNfXegfdOe0KlQyjFUR/PfaziAiGgIh594bUrCujs6haEddz1Eg1jhhcGYJzRV0jCEkg2@5hievCnuN6qFy9FAyK2N6o6g5oOC0yFjdjJARWdEueIJMxuht0iU4v0XNJ43YdNS5ENK8LLmPO@tSdgkB1B8aWiqSxXK13qQEz4KR5wfheDKdfSxbkYidIPhfDnO4fgE)

Ended up printing the strings newline-separated, since Forth doesn't have a native list format and newlines are cheaper than spaces

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f               \ start a new word definition
  >r              \ stick the divisor on the return stack (to get it out of the way)
  i /mod          \ get the quotient and remainder of dividing length by divisor
  rot             \ move the string starting-address to the top of the stack
  r> 0            \ move the divisor off the return stack and setup loop parameters
  do              \ loop from 0 to divisor  - 1
    over          \ copy the calculated substring-length to the top of the stack
    2dup          \ duplicate both address and substring-length
    cr            \ output a newline
    type          \ print a string of substring-length characters from the given address
    +             \ add the substring length to the current address
  loop            \ end the loop definition
  rot             \ move the remainder to the top of the stack
  cr type         \ output a newline and print the remaining remainder characters in the  string
;                 \ end the word definition
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 32 bytes

```
:l͍i:},,r[\>i
/?)1l$,'$L
\]$ak@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/98q52xvplWtjk5RdIxdJpe@vaZhjoqOuooPV0ysSmK2w///jk7OLq5u7h6eXt4KJgA)

Note that inputs are automatically coerced to the most appropriate value type (i.e. numbers will be cast to numerical values, which will not 'divide' correctly) and that inputs are separated by spaces. If you wish to include an input string that *contains* a space, it (and newlines) will need to be escaped (e.g. `Hello\ World!`)

Output is the groupings separated by `,`, followed by a new line, then the remainder (if any). As such, `,` and newlines in the input are not recommended (but will definitely display correctly).

### Explanation

The first line handles reading and parsing the inputs (reordered for legibility):

```
>              Entry point
 i:            Read string input, duplicate it
   l͍           Get its length
    i:         Get integer input, duplicate it
      ,,       Divide length by input, divide input string by grouping size (collect the bonus)
        r      Reverse the stack
         [     Pop the top N values to a new virtual stack (this value is the numerical input value)
          \    Enter output loop

          L    Top of the loop, sends IP to the left
         $     Print top of the stack (first substring)
      $,'      Push a , and print it
   )1l         Check if the length of the stack is >1
  ?            If true, skip next instruction (go top top of loop)
 /             If false, bounce to the last line

 \             Reflect IP to the right
  ]            Pop the virutal stack back to the top of the original stack
   $           Print the last substring
    ak         Push a newline
      @        Dump rest of the stack and terminate
```