# Split into three!

Tags: code-golf, string, array

> Given a string, you've to split it into groups of three characters (by padding `_` at the end).
>
> [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77310/split-string-into-n-pieces-or-pieces-of-length-n), but still it's different.

---

**Sample I/O:**

- `'abcde' -> 'abc', 'de_'`
- `'1234' -> '123', '4__'`
- `'' -> [] or falsey value`
- `'Three spree!' -> 'Thr', 'ee ', 'spr', 'ee!'`
- [6 MB string](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aruy7r9on8z4xst/ThreeSpreeText.txt?raw=1)

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes will win!

**Edit:** Finally, output is *unrestricted*.

Comment: Why special case the empty string? May we choose which character to use for the padding?

Comment: Is null considered a falsey value?

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz, falsey values are defined by the language, not the challenge author.

Answer (score 10):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
…___«3ô¨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOy@Pj4Q6uND285tOL/f0MjYxMA)
or as a [Test Suite](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/i9v9Rw7L4@PhDq40Pbzm04r/O/8Sk5JRULkMjYxMuJTDgCskoSk1VKC4AkooA)

**Explanation**

```
…___«      # append "___" to input
     3ô    # split into groups of 3
       ¨   # discard the last group
```

Answer (score 8):

## Python 3, <s>58 47</s> 34 bytes

<s>I'm sure someone else can do better</s> Someone else did better. Thanks Jo King for <s>-11</s> -24 bytes!

Output is unrestricted, welcome to tuple hell. Returns empty list ([falsy](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EIy@/RAGIo2M1//8HAA)) on empty input

```py
lambda x:[*zip(*[iter(x+"__")]*3)]
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCKlqrKrNAQys6syS1SKNCWyk@XkkzVstYM/Z/QVFmXolGmoaSoZGxiamSpuZ/AA)

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript, 25 bytes

```
s=>`${s}__`.match(/.../g)
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNFNSkxKzdHNy09J/Z9m@7/Y1i5Bpbq4Nj4@QS83sSQ5Q0NfT09PP13zf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RnSCoZGxSYJOQkIsUFWBRpqm5n8A)

Answer (score 5):

## APL+WIN <s>36 24</s> 22 bytes

12 bytes saved as a result of output now being de-restricted and using the code in @Adám's first comment modified to work in APL+WIN and a further 2 with his second comment. Thanks.

```
(⌈(↑⍴s)÷3)3⍴(s←⎕),'__'
```

Prompts for input of the string and outputs the result as a nx3 array

[Try it online! Courtesy of Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/5rPOrp0HjUNvFR75ZizcPbjTWNgSyNYqACoEJNHfX4ePX/QIX/07jUDY2MTdS5gIzEpOSUVDArJKMoNVWhuABIKqoDAA)

Comment: @Adám. Throws a domain error in APL+WIN at the right most ⍴

Comment: Fails on `''`, no? I think OP (for some strange reason) requires the result to be `0` (with any rank).

Comment: @Adám It produces a 0 x 3 array. The OP now appears to want "falsey" for a null input. With the spec keeping on changing I am going to bow out at this point and leave my answer as its stands! Thanks for your improvements.

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```perl
"@_\__"=~/.../g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BjsIgEIbvPMVImgCRra7bvdjQ9AW8eVsNWXVc2dS2KTXGGPfV62CtywGY7/9moMam@OxOHmGJvp3PF1WD0NLVmyxJ2fECeaiMZADie7PdoYDnMhl8BSQ0iB1asdbBeZ99JC@ldwgFJ7GD858PTs@XhwYRfE37SPS9hEIv4XBQ1FcjsWYqZeeDK1A@fqiuNOF4kZHTUaWMrwu3xUeip3qWUui8hN/KlVKMhd6TqFR4NawXzqmXahX8unFlCzxyAG8ZAIf46cEYhgHE@KrkKbsxf9rA/trx3K6s5eZvEsfx5Ke7dXc)

Comment: 15 with `"@_\__"=~/.../g`. There were other 16s: `(pop.__)=~/.../g` or `map/.../g,pop.__`.

Comment: Thx to @Grimy for the tip on \. It shaved off 1 byte and I learned something new.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, <s>51 50 48 27</s> 25

```js
b=>(b+"__").match(/.../g)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcnLDkAwEEDRva@gqzZixGPLT7BvZmq8Uioqfr@sxeYuzl3xRm/O5bgyQmKb7W7gMDaBmlZSKrQWCja8zCxzAMgnFYzbvbMM1k1ylALJDCyUij5elFX9wz/Uzydz3B1vk3eHBw)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! :) But ... https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185808/58974

Comment: @Shaggy I didn't even see that ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: No worries, it happens.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 19 bytes

```perl6
{$_~"__"~~m:g/.../}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WiW@Tik@XqmuLtcqXV9PT0@/9r81V1p@kYJGTmZearGmQjWXgkJxYqWCnloaV@3/xKTklFQuQyNjEy6ukIyi1FSF4gIgqQgA)

Pads the string by two underscores then splits the string into chunks of three characters. Returns as an array of Match objects.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 bytes

+1 byte to special case the empty string. Can save 2 if we can choose our padding character.

```
©ò3 ú'_3
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=qfIzIPonXzM&input=IjEyMzQi)

```
©ò3 ú'_3     :Implicit input of string
©            :Logical AND with
 ò3          :Split into chunks of 3
    ú'_3     :Right pad each with "_" to length 3
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
é☻εgP▀╪
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8202ee6750dfd8&i=%22abcde%22%0A%221234%22%0A%22%22%0A%22Three+spree%21%22&a=1&m=2)

For an empty string input, the result is an empty array, which is a falsey value in stax.

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 11 bytes

```
q'_3*+3/);p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v1A93lhL21hf07rg///EpOSUVAA)

For empty input this gives an empty string, which is falsy.

#### How it works

```
q     e# Read input as a string
'_    e# Push char '_'
3*    e# String formed by that char repeated 3 times
+     e# Concatenate to input string
3/    e# Split in groups of 3, the last of which may be shorter. Gives array of strings
);    e# Detach last string from the array and delete it
p     e# Print string representation of the array
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 10 bytes

```
$
__
!`...
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX4UrPp5LMUFPT@///8Sk5JRULkMjYxMurpCMotRUheICIKkIAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
$
__
```

Append two `_`s, in case the last group needs to be padded.

```
!`...
```

Match as many groups of three as possible, outputting the matches themselves rather than the count. (In Retina 1 this would be `L` instead of `!`.)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>28</s> 21 bytes

-7: No longer requires falsy (`False`) value on empty input

```
Partition[#,3,1,1,_]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7PyCxqCSzJDM/L1pZx1jHEAjjY9X@BxRl5pVEK@vapTk4ZyQWJSaXpBYVOyjHquk7VHMpJSYlp6Qq6XApGRoZm4BoEA7JKEpNVSguAJKKSly1/wE)

Takes a list of characters as input. Returns a list of 3-tuples of characters padded with `Blank`s (`_`).

---

#### <s>34</s> 27 bytes

```
StringPartition[#<>"__",3]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P7ikKDMvPSCxqCSzJDM/L1rZxk4pPl5JxzhW7X8AUKokWlnXLs1BOVZN36GaSykxKTklVUmHS8nQyNgERINwSEZRaqpCcQGQVFTiqv0PAA)

String input, list of strings output

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 67 bytes

```c
i;f(char*_){for(;*_;puts(""))for(i=3;i--;)putchar(*_?*_++:95);_=0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3NDoIwEITvPMXaxKTlJ1HBg67El/CmpMFShBKRlHIifXZs4TKZnZl8K5KPEMvSYk1FU@qQs7n@aYohx2EyIyWEMR@0eYptkiBzqR/SkN9DHkXXy5khzw9ol2/Z9pTNAawgI0czPovc3UDKt6gkib09ntJsc5s@Gi0ljIPTHQnAYgDrv96Aclh1y1BFkceCzzrIoaYbXBXMrWHQrqgpoVqaSfcM9tWrJ3HnSxvY5Q8)

Always returns a falsey value (0).

Comment: Do you even need to return anything?

Comment: [63 bytes](https://tio.run/##Fco7DoAgDADQWU5hmFoIk3HQxngWrEEZ/ITqZDg76vry2C3MpUQKwKtPRvAJRwIyQud9CWiN@EMcGorOEX76RzAyGrG271qkXDYfd8D6UVUA7SeeNZLKqrw)

Answer (score 2):

## **Ruby, <strike>73</strike> 42 bytes**

```
a=gets
a.length!=0?a.scan(/.{1,3}/).map{|s|(s+'_'*3)[0,3]}:'falsey value'
```

Edit: As falsey value looks like it's not required:

```
gets.scan(/.{1,3}/).map{|s|(s+'_'*3)[0,3]}
```

Comment: The maximum padding is of 2 characters, so `'_'*2` would be enough, for which a literal `'__'` is shorter. But if you add the padding in advance then simply not match the pieces shorter than 3 characters, is shorter: `puts"#{gets}__".scan /.../`. (Note that without the explicit printing that is considered `irb` not `ruby`.)

Comment: [29 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X0m5WiW@Nj5eSa84OTFPQ19PT09fs7oms6ZAIbP2///EpOSU1H/5BSWZ@XnF/3XzAA) (note: -2 bytes with `_1` syntax and -2 if a different padding character is allowed)

Comment: @AsoneTuhid - That's different enough to be posted as a separate answer! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <strike>128</strike> <strike>126</strike> <strike>94</strike> <strike>67</strike> 63 bytes

*63 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat.*

```c
f(char*k){for(;*k;k++)printf("%c%c%c\n",*k,*++k?:95,*++k?:95);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///P00jOSOxSCtbszotv0jDWivbOltbW7OgKDOvJE1DSTUZBGPylHS0snW0tLWz7a0sTeEMTeva/7mJmXkaiTplmmBjtMqsq7kUgACoNzEpOSVVSdNaQV9foSS1uEQhObE4lav2PwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
s3o€“___”
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of characters which yields a list of lists of characters (an empty input yields empty output).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9qZWxsef//czNv4oKs4oCcX19f4oCd/8OHxZLhuZj//2FiY2RlZmdoaWprbG0)**

#### How?

```
s3o€“___” - Link: list of characters
s3        - split into chunks of three
   €      - for each chunk:
  o       -   OR (vectorises):
    “___” -     list of characters = ['_', '_', '_']
```

Notes:
The `€` is only necessary to handle the edge case of an empty input.
A full program can drop a trailing `”`, but here we can't do that as the printing behaviour of a full program smashes everything together.

---

Equivalent 9:

```
o3ÐƤ“___”
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9qZWxsef//bzPDkMak4oCcX19f4oCd/8OHxZLhuZj//2FiY2RlZmdoaWprbG0)

---

Alternative 9:

```
;“___”s3Ṗ
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9qZWxsef//O@KAnF9fX@KAnXMz4bmW/8OHxZLhuZj//2FiY2RlZmdoaWprbG0)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 16 bytes

```
[:}:_3]\'___',~]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8D/aqtYq3jg2Rj0@Pl5dpy72vyaXkp6CepqtnrqCjkKtlUJaMRdXanJGvkKagnpiUnJKqjqca2hkbILghWQUpaYqFBcASUWEqPp/AA)

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>19</s> 17 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to ngn!

```
{-1_0N 3#x,"___"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qWtcw3sBPwVi5QkcpPj5eqfZ/mrqGUmJSckqqkrWSoZGxCZACopCMotRUheICIKmopPkfAA)

Comment: k: `(0N;3)` -> `0N 3`

Answer (score 1):

## Java 10, <s>116</s> 113 bytes

```java
s->{s+="__";int l=s.length()/3,i=l;var r=new String[l];for(;i-->0;)r[i]=s.substring(i*3,i*3+3);return l<1?0>1:r;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##rVDNUoMwEL7zFCunpJVYxJMRHB/Aeqg3humEkLbBNDBJwOl0eHZMoXr0oped2Z/vb2vWs6iuPkaumLXwyqQ@BwBSO2F2jAtYX1qAt7IW3AFHG2ek3oPF1M@HwBfrmJMc1qAhhdFG2dku03C7DalnAZVaooTeuwPCd8mtTBXtmQGTavEJM1muCrprDKIyirIVxSaXhUfZrrTTHsmFBy6SZYKpEa4zGtRT/LzK4kdDh5FeTLRdqbyJq5e@kRUcfZar3bwAhucgm5N14kiazpHWr5zSqPY/IJ2TirwYw06WuGaGoR841oSjkJW8EiHGU/a/UcX3ycOvTNNV@B9S7wcjBNjW15tvySEYxi8)

Or **<s>104</s> 101 bytes** if an empty array instead of `false` is allowed as output..

```java
s->{s+="__";int l=s.length()/3;var r=new String[l];for(;l-->0;)r[l]=s.substring(l*3,l*3+3);return r;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##pU9JbsMwDLz7FaxPUlOri3sTHKAPaC7trQgCWVYSuYpskJKLIPDbXWXrA5oDCZKDmeG0alBF23xP2ikieFfWHzIA64PBtdIGFscV4COg9ZuvJWh2HoG4TMiYpUZBBathAR4qmKiYH2hW5atVLpMOuIqEM34Ttow/lnJQCFh583PVdEu57pBJVxTzJ8kxHRKDYk0nnLn78iHVrOQSTYjoAeU4yaNxH2uXjC/@Q2cb2KUE7O9bxS/v7ymYnehiEH2CgvOsTclFDNaJN0S1JxG6M415oVmuat2YnPNTyv8IPL@Ur7fwb@F@btEYoD71u6vOmI3TLw)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->{                             // Method with String as both parameter and return-type
  s+="__";                       //  Append two "_" to the input-String
  int l=s.length()/3;            //  Get the length, integer-divided by 3
  var r=new String[l];           //  Create a string-array with that many parts
  for(;l-->0;)                   //  Loop `l` in the range (l, 0]:
    r[l]=                        //   Set the `l`'th value of the array to:
         s.substring(l*3,l*3+3); //   Get the substring of size 3 from index `l*3` from `s`
  return r;}                     //  Return the array
```

Comment: An empty array is now allowed

Answer (score 1):

### [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 74 bytes

Just append two underscores '_' at the end of the input to make sure they get printed if the length of the input isn't a factor of 3.

```
s=>Enumerable.Range(0,(s.Length+2)/3).Select(i=>(s+"__").Substring(i*3,3))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jcxBC4JAEAXgu79i29NsmpV2M/emEHgqoaPoNuqCbbG7gv/epARv4RwezHvwCbMTRo5pr8TZWC1V410S1T9Rl1WHc8U5qUk8mpgvk38tVYNw8MD4GarGtm7A9iHzb9ihsCBjDsalRUGnqq9@EMht6IWMjZFTAy0r8cBpzl@ZNBaYn750UooWBhJzctfSYiYVwsBY5Cwv3c1H2Zc5BuFppUL@MHmrEYl5T7lZyY0f)

Comment: [67](https://tio.run/##jcwxC8IwEAXg3V8RM93ZWtG61WarIHRTcBApbby2AU0lSdF/H4sW3MQbHtx78Ek7l1b5ba/lxjqjdBPuMt3fyJTVlcZKCFaz1NtUaHowpd0JbJSTblwbrHARn6M9XUk6gCJUmAqwAS8KjtG@rz4CqFkcxog@mdTAy0peaJgPXa6sA4y2nclK2cKTpYIdjXKUK03wREwm35fPx@P4ZpareP2nwn4wh9YQMXsfcvon518 "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online")

Comment: [57](https://tio.run/##jYxBC4IwGIbv/oo1CL6RCWandOukENhJoWPM9ZkDm7Ep2K83sWMXLy/P4X0e5fbK6SkbjEpcb7V5@pfUDC@0smoxUY20QpCa8Mlx4YICW1T9VZoPAPqacaG3URKewe3o/U5ZUAzVLwPaj9iJEsqm2KuByko9cD6UXa5dDyzIOptK1cBIuCA3q3uEkbHYWzDXBoEtYniIjis88ieWjUUk7j3vZkVg@gI "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 34 bytes

```
{"${it}__".chunked(3).dropLast(1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcuxDsIgEIDhvU9xIQ53g02MW6P1Bdh8gIYU0EvxSih1ITw7NvHfvuFf1hxY2tcE8APgMyeWF8F5BM1bvv09wr0VdSqc6zSpfn7vsjiLV@ptWqM2W8YL1eZ3gY9hQYLSwVE85hwEPSZnrGZxSI9BKaKuQnOR5x8)

Comment: this does not work, try `{"${it}___".chunked(3).dropLast(1)}`

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 55 bytes

```c
i;f(char*s){for(;i%4|*s;)putchar(++i%4?*s?*s++:95:10);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU3LDoIwELzzFWsTkpZiAooHqcSf8KYcsLTyiJW05YR8e20l2UxmZ3Zm@f7FuXM9k5h3jU4MWeRHY9bHxTcxjEyzDTqm1CvXxPihtDyfyjwjbHXvpleYLBH8w1YYa@515XdAzZO3AqWB5odjsbENb50WAszkcYciWFkE4WmvLAxVxoZLwQZKQy0EbYQKJN7Kh5r4a5i0NyRGWAs7a0Ugbh8KpWMw12h1Pw)

Comment: Using 9(`\t`) instead of 10(`\n`) should be fine, but that's not main point

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 90 bytes

This uses Bash features rather than a combination of more traditional Bourne shell plus *nix commands (which one version I created ended up at 205 bytes). I cheated by using the dodge of adding two _ characters to the string.

```
c=;read a;a=${a}__;while (($(echo ${#a})>2));do b=${a:0:3};c=$c\ $b;a=${a#$b};done;echo $c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcuxCoQwDADQXwmYod1EN0P9EkGSNFpFTrgbHKTf3lO6vyf8S6VooK9xBCYOeHOeZ7rSdhg4h840nYB3w9mPnfcUT5BXDe3QZ9KAOgFKnQ1KfsDHqC4thUWjLWva9j8)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/), <s>58</s> 35 bytes

```
$args-split'(...)'-ne''|% *ht 3 '_'
```

-23 bytes thanks to [mazzy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80745/mazzy).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7BDoIwDIbve4pKimVmkCicTHgL7wRkiskCc8NoAjw7FtAe1v7f1yy13Vs732hjZqwgh2HG0t197K159BQlSSIpbjXRGMKh6SEFKmiehMDu5nNSJCIqq2utScEyqFoXJBXT4ynNFshdZcUPMsD2Zcy2seq/ujROa/CW390iOCsGiolakIQRwkEAF1r@5sPXYrFlx/Oe70e75gAj1rF@spFnwMFNgZjmLw)

Comment: Nice. 1) You can count a code that can be extracted into a ps1-file and executed. 2) See [shortcuts](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111526/80745). 3) [Try to golf more](https://tio.run/##NYzBDoIwDIbve4pKigUzSBROJryF9wVkiskCuGE0AZ59FtAe2v7f17Tv3tq6RhvjsSpGj6W9u8T15jFQlKZpTEmriaYQDs0AGSg/C4HdzRUkSURUVtdak4RlkbVWFEumx1OWL5CnzNUPMsD2Zcx2seq/ujRWa3A9990iOEsGkolcUAwThKMALuz5zQcKQLVly/seKxZrDjBinegnm/gMONo5ELP/Ag "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

### [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 27 bytes

```sed
s:$:__:
s:...:& :g
s: _*$::
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v9hKxSo@3oqr2EpPT89KTcEqHchUiNdSsbL6/7@SKz@by9HJmcvQyNiEKzEpOSWVKySjKDVVobgASCoCAA)

It gets a bit tricky regarding the empty string input, since sed has no meaning of a falsy value. So to deal with this, I provide you with two possible interpretations of the rules to validate my submission:

---

**A.** You essentially provide nothing as input, not even a trailing newline (as it is the case with all the examples, including that 6 Mb file).

**Usage:**

```sh
echo -n ""|sed -f script
```

**Output:** nothing is printed, because sed doesn't even run the script without input.

---

**B.** One could consider as falsy value for sed to be an unique string, i.e., returned only when the input is an empty string.

**Usage:**

```sh
echo ""|sed -f script
```

**Output:**

```
__
```

---

I prefer the first interpretation so much more, as I believe it to be the closest to the intended rule, but the last one helps if you run the script using that TIO link.

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 30 chars, 60 bytes

```
{(3/⍳3÷⍨≢v)⊂v←⍵,'_'⍴⍨3∣3-3∣≢⍵}
```

test:

```
  f←{(3/⍳3÷⍨≢v)⊂v←⍵,'_'⍴⍨3∣3-3∣≢⍵}
  ⎕fmt f 'abcde'
┌2────────────┐
│┌3───┐ ┌3───┐│
││ abc│ │ de_││
│└────┘ └────┘2
└∊────────────┘
  ⎕fmt f '1234'
┌2────────────┐
│┌3───┐ ┌3───┐│
││ 123│ │ 4__││
│└────┘ └────┘2
└∊────────────┘
  ⎕fmt f ''
┌0──┐
│┌0┐│
││ ││
│└¯┘2
└∊──┘
  ⎕fmt f 'Three spree!'
┌4──────────────────────────┐
│┌3───┐ ┌3───┐ ┌3───┐ ┌3───┐│
││ Thr│ │ ee │ │ spr│ │ ee!││
│└────┘ └────┘ └────┘ └────┘2
└∊──────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
s3Zz”_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/YOKrqUcPc@P@H27X1HzWtOTrp4c4ZmpH//yslJiWnpCrpKCgZGhmbgGgQDskoSk1VKC4AkopKAA)

### How it works

```
s3Zz”_ - Main link. Takes a string S on the left
s3     - Split into chunks of 3
  Z    - Transpose
   z”_ - Transpose, using "_" as a filler
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
3ẇ∩\_ÞṪ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIz4bqH4oipXFxfw57huaoiLCIiLCJUaHJlZSBzcHJlZSEiXQ==)

### How?

```
3ẇ∩\_ÞṪ
3ẇ      # Split into chunks of three
  ∩     # Transpose
   \_ÞṪ # Transpose with "_" as filler
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `grouping.extras`, 27 bytes

```factor
[ 3 95 pad-groups 3 group ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
³'_3Ŀ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDMiVCMydfMyVDNCVCRiZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PWFiY2RlJmZsYWdzPQ==)

```
³'_ƬṬ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDMiVCMyUyMCdfJTIwdHJhbnNwb3NlX3dpdGhfZmlsbGVyJTIwdHJhbnNwb3NlJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9YWJjZGUmZmxhZ3M9dg==)

##### Explanation

```python
³'_3Ŀ  '# Implicit input
³       # Split into threes
    Ŀ   # Left-justify each,
 '_    '# padding with "_"s
   3    # to length 3
        # Implicit output
```

```python
³'_ƬṬ  '# Implicit input
³       # Split into threes
   Ƭ    # Transpose with
 '_    '# filler "_"
    Ṭ   # Tranpose again
        # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://haskell.org/), 40 bytes

```haskell
f(a:b:c:t)=[a,b,c]:f t
f _=[]
f.(++"__")
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Babel Node)](https://babeljs.io/), 45 bytes

```javascript
_=>_.match(/.{1,3}/g).map(a=>a.padEnd(3,`_`))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNFNSkxKzdHNy09J/Z9m@z/e1i5eLzexJDlDQ1@v2lDHuFY/XRMoUKCRaGuXqFeQmOKal6JhrJMQn6Cp@T85P684PydVLyc/XSNNQz0koyg1VaG4AEgqqmtqcqFJGxoZm2ARBgr9BwA)

Comment: [44](https://tio.run/##bYlBDoIwEADvvkJP7CayRPFaOPkD72VpF9DUtqHE75eeiZdJZubDP05mfcetHnkUV/tgJU8qa9Vp@vJmFmiIeuqbGYtHYNUxRbZPb6G9DnpAzCb4FJyQCzNMUL2WVeScYuGlQjwd9u3ePv7kkvIO)

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
s3;€⁾__ḣ€3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/Y2PpR05pHjfvi4x/uWAxkGv8/3H500sOdM/4DAA)

It feels like an 8 or 9 should be possible, but haven’t found one yet.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <strike>10</strike> 9 bytes

```
Pc+z*3\_3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyBZu0rLOCbe@P//xKTklFQA)

-1 from u_ndefined.

Is it ok if it throws an error on empty input? (does that count as falsey)

Comment: It works on TIO, but not on Pyth compiler/executor. Is there a reason? (i.e. Pyth compiler/executor is outdated?)

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyBZu0rLOCbe@P//xKTklFQA "Pyth – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), <s>34</s> 23 bytes

```
PadRight&"_"&3=>@Chop&3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fpmBl@z8gMSUoMz2jRE0pXknN2NbOwTkjv0DN@L9fampKcbRKQUFyeixXQFFmXklIanGJc2JxanF0mo5CNJcCECglJiWnpCrpQDiGRsYmMDaMDskoSk1VKC4AkopKXLGx/wE)

### Explanation (outdated)

```
{On[#_-1,PadRight&"_"&3,_]}@Chop&3
                           @Chop&3    chop the input string into groups of 3s
{On[#_-1               ,_]}           on the last group
        ,PadRight                         pad it
                     &3                   to length three
                 &"_"                     with underscores
```

Comment: Would you save anything by padding *all* the elements instead of just the last one?

Comment: @Shaggy Good point! I’ll look into it

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
Ｅ⪪Ｓ³…⁺ι__³
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3sUAjuCAns0TDM6@gtCS4BCiarqGpo2AMxM6VyTmpzhn5BRoBOaXFGpk6Ckrx8UpgSU1N6///DY2MTbj@65blAAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
  Ｓ         Input string
 ⪪ ³        Split into groups of up to 3 characters
Ｅ           Map over each group
      ι     Current group
     ⁺      Concatenated with
       __   Literal `__`
    …    ³  Moulded to length 3
            Each group implicitly printed on its own line
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 31 bytes

```scala
(s+"___").grouped(3).toSeq.init
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcqxCsIwFIXhPU9xzJQgFLROgoO7TrqJlLS5rZGSxuYKgvjsMeKiQ5fLufxfbExv0lBfqWHsjfOgB5O3EdsQnkIIwFKLVsU1Djw63@k86Hb6PmdskFScy6qqpC66cbgHsqrUBQ9ZFc47TgBCxtx71Spp6saS/ICdi6zFf10sy9VknAzHy0iEGPKd/aBXegM)

**Explanation**

```scala
(s+"___")       // add "___"
  .grouped(3)   // make groups of 3
  .toSeq        // change to Seq
  .init         // take all but last
```

Comment: You'll have to add some part of the function definition in, otherwise you won't know where `s` is coming from

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), <s>30</s> 29 bytes

```
~:1+%,~:1+!"`"*+,~:1+!"`"*+,,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/v87KUFtVB0QqKiUoaWkjM3X@/0/OT0lNz89JAwA)

Outputs nothing for an empty input, otherwise outputs strings of length 3 separated by NUL characters.

Explanation:

```
~                               Push character of input to stack
 :1+                            Duplicate input and add 1
    %                           Modulo top 2 values of stack and push result
                                If input was -1 (end of stream), calculate -1%0 -> halt
                                Otherwise calculate input%(input+1) -> input
     ,                          Pop and output character
      ~                         Push character of input to stack
       :1+!                     Duplicate input, add 1 and perform logical NOT
           "`"*                 Multiply by 96 (ASCII code for '`')
                                This returns 96 or 0 depending on the result of the NOT
               +                Add the top 2 values from the stack and push the result
                                If the input was -1 (end of stream), pushes -1+96=95, or the ASCII code for '_'
                                Otherwise pushes input+0
                ,               Pop and output character
                 ~:1+!"`"*+,    Same block again to handle the third character
                            ,   Output a NUL character (stack is empty, so popping from stack just returns 0)

The instruction pointer wraps around at the end, looping the entire line.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, <s>62</s> <s>61</s> 59 bytes

```
z(a:b:c:d)=[a,b,c]:z d
f s=takeWhile(/="___")$z$s++cycle"_"
```

Infinite lists and strings!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcxLCoAgEADQfacYBhdKQnvBc7SIkNEMRfuQbvLy1jvAC1SSz7n3xklZ5dQm9ELSSreqBtuwQ9GVkp9DzJ5PGo0xKFhjZRzd67JHg/2geIKG@4lnBQY7YPjPC/sH)

Answer (score 0):

## Rust, 93 bytes

Works for ASCII input strings. Empties the input string and returns a `Vec<String>`.

```rust
|mut s:String|{s+="__";let mut v=vec![];while s.len()>2{let t=s.split_off(3);v.push(s);s=t}v}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##PU/BboMwDD2Hr3BzSjoUae2NKN1H9FhViLGkjRQCwoYeIN/OYKiTLFv2e8/P7gekxUVoKh@FhCljwRI4MMvcDARYXKn38TFP@GF4WXK9wRsymtHWh9tdv54@WEAV7Lrgcpo2AhlU2AVPZeucOEs9qm7Ap0Cp0VAa08J0tlv52A2EYOCWMcZ5vuXq@13rH@see/N5Ov/HNrkrH6ktPdleSNVUnZhxhv3conB924gjSqkz5toe/Gr09lqfZN1KoxAPgk8JzAWm4ivxHHwOTnhVhzZaIf/UKUvLLw)

Answer (score 0):

## [GoLang](https://golang.org/), 84 bytes

```golang
func(x string)[]string{return regexp.MustCompile("...").FindAllString(x+"__",-1)}(s)
```

[Try it !](https://play.golang.org/p/aWoIr7va06X)

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 93 bytes

```
	S =INPUT
	S =S DUPL('_',REMDR(3 - REMDR(SIZE(S),3),3))
R	S LEN(3) . OUTPUT REM . S	:S(R)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/nzNYwdbTLyA0hAvEClZwCQ3w0VCPV9cJcvV1CdIwVtBVgLCCPaNcNYI1dYxBSJMrCKjcx9VPw1hTQU/BPzQEaAJIIZATzGkVrBGkyeXq5/L/f2JSckoqAA)

SNOBOL has a size limit on the length of its input (1023 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 40 bytes

```julia
s->[(s*"__")[i:i+3] for i=1:3:length(s)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPifZpuUmp6Z979Y1y5ao1hLKT5eSTM60ypT2yhWIS2/SCHT1tDK2ConNS@9JEOjWDP2f2peCpdDcUZ@uUKahlJiUkpicVpiWmJKmpLmfwA)

Comment: [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAe68IT1oUSDch6R8RsalbG2KHNerQ323mvCOBfguOW9gpFe6sNoOJIe35kKz6z1JnJTdiXYWayVA7LCUkX018XE/trhiDyxKlgM0DIyB4FEqVHw)

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 10 bytes

```
"___"+3/);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/Xyk@Pl5J21hf0/p/wn9DI2MA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <sup><s>9</s></sup> 6 bytes

```
TT'_C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/PyREPd7Z@P///4lJySmpAA)

look ma, no unicode!(-3)

### Explanation

```
TT'_C3
    C3 cut into pieces of 3
 T'_   transpose, padding with underscore
T      transpose again
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>27</s> 21 bytes

```ruby
p"#{$_}__".scan /.../
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BJuVolvjY@XkmvODkxT0FfT09P////xKTklNR/@QUlmfl5xf918wA)

-6 bytes thanks to [vrintle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/83605/vrintle)

Comment: Saved 6 bytes more, [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BJuVolvjY@XkmvODkxT0FfT09P////xKTklNR/@QUlmfl5xf918wA "Ruby – Try It Online"). BTW, do you know why it fails for multiline input? Though, it's not a part of this challenge..

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](https://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Jan-14)</sup>, 8 bytes

```
⬚@_↯¯1_3
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__ZiDihpAg4qyaQF_ihq_CrzFfMwoKZiAiYWJjZGUiCmYgIjEyMzQiCmYgIiIKZiAiVGhyZWUgc3ByZWUhIgo=)

Answer (score 0):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 8 bytes (16 nibbles)

In literal form:

```
`/3;_<3:$"__"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWaxP0ja3jbYytVJTi45UgYlApmBIA)

```
`/             chunks of
  3              3 characters
   ;_            for input string
               then, apply map(\chunk->...):
     <3          take first 3 characters of
       :$"__"    concatenation of chunk and "__"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 21 bytes

```
\__|!II^/3P[[gb>]3B]`
```

[Try it Online!](https://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=%5C__%7C!II%5E%2F3P%5B%5Bgb%3E%5D3B%5D%60&inputs=Hello%2C%20World!)

Outputs groups of 3 separated by newlines.

## Explanation:

```
\__|                  take input and concatenate "__"
    !                 disable implicit output
     I                save characters of the input in consecutive memory slots
      I^              get length of the input
        /3            divide by 3 to get n
          [...]`      loop n times (ignoring any values after the decimal point)

[...]3                loop 3 times
 g                    get the character at the pointer
  b                   add this character to the print buffer
   >                  move pointer right
      B               print contents of buffer and reset
```